# Выполнить только одно из одновременных событий

Tags: javascript, события

### Описание

У меня есть некая функция (для ясности назовем `foo`), которая должна выполнятся если пользователь опустил курсор на элемент. Поскольку мне неизвестно какое устройство у пользователя я прикрепляю все возможные обработчики:

```js
element.addEventListener(`mousedown`, (event) => {
    foo();
});
element.addEventListener(`pointerdown`, (event) => {
    foo();
});
element.addEventListener(`touchstart`, (event) => {
    foo();
});
```

Теперь мне надо делать так, чтобы когда в тот же момент заработает один из обработчиков, остальные молчали, чтобы функция выполнилась 1 раз, а не 3. Делаю я это вот так:

```js
const controller = new AbortController();
await new Promise((resolve) => {
    element.addEventListener(`mousedown`, (event) => {
        resolve();
    }, { signal: controller.signal });
    element.addEventListener(`pointerdown`, (event) => {
        resolve();
    }, { signal: controller.signal });
    element.addEventListener(`touchstart`, (event) => {
        resolve();
    }, { signal: controller.signal });
});
foo();
controller.abort();
```

Работает неплохо, но работает 1 раз. Чтобы заработало заново мне надо будет создать функцию которая сгенерирует эту же конструкцию каждый раз после окончания.

### Проблема

Ну решение, как решение работает. Но если считать что кроме `mousedown`, `pointerdown`, `touchstart` ещё и добавить `mousemove`, `pointermove`, `touchmove` и ещё куча таких же обработчиков, то, по-моему, выглядит нудно.

### Вопрос

Есть альтернативное, более хорошее решение?
Или же можно упростить эту конструкцию?

---

### ЧаВо

> — Почему не использовать только `pointer...` слушатели? Они же универсальные.
> — Они иногда неправильно работают. К примеру, `pointermove` останавливается 24-30 кадров после опускания мыши при использовании на мобильных устройствах.

> — Почему не использовать для каждого устройства свои правильные обработчики?
> — Я бы с радостью. Но как на 100% верно узнать эту "правильность" обработчиков? Обработчики везде присутствуют, но не реагируют. `navigator.userAgent` дает неправильной информации. Какие ещё способы мне попробовать?

Comment: а почему просто не проверить наличие нужных обработчиков и повесить только их?

Comment: @Grundy это решение провалилось сегодня. У нас повесили какой-то touchboard который как бы является планшетом, но установлен ОС телефона и так же умеет работать как компьютер. Во время проверки сайта в режиме ПК заработала только `touchmove`, но в `userAgent` был написан, что это ПК.

Comment: а причем тут userAgent и проверка поддержки функциональности?

Comment: @Grundy ну а как по-другому проверить наличие нужных обработчиков? Я проверяю через `userAgent` и вешаю к примеру `mousemove` если это ПК, `touchmove` если это планшет или телефон...

Comment: userAgent не определяет наличие или отсутствие чего-то. Там в принципе любая строка может быть

Comment: @Grundy имею ввиду `navigator.userAgent`. Если все же нет, то скажите пожалуйста, как определить тип устройства?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152183/discussion-between-grundy-and-eccs0103).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое полученное событие замыкает обработчик на себя. Он перестаёт реагировать на события других типов:

```
const makeGate = f => {
    let password = undefined;
    return (key, event) => {
        if (password === key) {
            f(event);
        } else if (password === undefined) {
            password = key;
            f(event);
        }
    };
};

const addEventListeners = (element, types, listener) => {
    const gate = makeGate(listener);
    types.forEach(
        type => element.addEventListener(type, event => gate(type, event))
    );
};

...

    addEventListeners(
        element,
        ['mousedown', 'pointerdown', 'touchstart'],
        event => foo()
    );
```

Comment: Хорошее решение, а также хорошо работает. Спасибо.

Comment: по-моему, в итоге срабатывает pointerdown и на десктопе и на мобилке, хотя по сравнению с кучкой if выглядит получше. А еще учитывая претензии к pointer - его бы лучше не использовать, отдавая предпочтение mousedown/touch.

Comment: Это можно сделать сочетая задержку на первом вызове и отключение неприоритетных типов на последующих.

Answer (score 1):

Наверху есть решение с замыканием и созданием всего списка событий из массива. По итогу, лично у меня постоянно срабатывает `pointerdown` (к которому у автора есть претензии), независимо от порядка. Ну и фактически создаются все 2-3 варианта события, если они имеются в браузере.

Мое решение - проверять событие из списка на наличие в объекте `window` и вешать обработчик первое не равное `undefined`. Из плюсов - можно задавать любой порядок, не создает лишних событий. Из минусов завязано на проверку наличия событий в объекте `window`.

**ВАЖНО!!** ключевой момент порядок обработчиков в массиве, на мой взгляд, оптимальный touch, mouse, pointer - но этот момент уточняется на практике

```js
const addEventListeners = (element, types, listener) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
     if (window[`on${types[i]}`] !== undefined) {
       element.addEventListener(types[i], e => listener(e));
       return;
    } 
  }
};

const foo = e => {
  console.log(e.type, 'event');
  result.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div>${e.type}, event</div>`);
}
const element = document.querySelector('.button');
const result = document.querySelector('.result');

addEventListeners(
  element,
  ['touchstart','mousedown', 'pointerdown'],
  event => foo(event)
);
```

```html
<button class='button'>кнопка</button>
<div class='result'></div>
```

Идея отсюда [Существование события в браузере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5) , и еще можно здесь посмотреть [Как ваш браузер обрабатывает прикосновения к экрану телефона (js touch events)](https://habr.com/ru/articles/592317/).

Comment: События `ontouchmove` и `onmousemove` существуют. И все остальные слушатели тоже. Проблема в том, что они не реагируют или реагируют неправильно. Посмотрите в чат под вопросом. Там я объяснил множество из ситуаций, которые вы описали.

Comment: ну так да - вы определяете событие и еще смотрите userAgent, который мягко говоря не совсем достоверен. Какая разница какое устройство, главное чтобы события были. Проверять по порядку-pointer-touch-mouse и вешать только первое нашедшееся.

Comment: Ну хоть так. Но как я уже писал, к примеру `pointermove` есть, но оно работает неправильно. Если проверка выберет его, то мой код попросту не обнаружит движение мыши.

Comment: `...у меня постоянно срабатывает pointerdown (к которому у автора есть претензии)...` - теперь поставьте в вашем коде вместо обработчиков `[ 'pointermove', 'touchmove', 'mousemove' ]` и попробуйте ваше решение **именно с телефона**. Поймете к чему у автора претензии.

Comment: решается изменением порядка обработчиков в списке и проверкой на практике. Т.е. на мой взгляд, оптимальный - touch, mouse, pointer, но это не 100% идеально.

Comment: Вот с последним уточнением уже все работает. Но я бы предлагал все-таки убрать `pointer...` совсем. `mouse...` работает для ПК, `touch...` для мобильного, а вот `pointer...` вроде универсальный, но не работает. Точнее он все же работает, но работает неправильно.

Comment: а pointer это как бы универсальное событие, по задумке - должно к 100% его поддержке прийти. И он ресурсов не кушает - до него вообще не доходит чаще всего, а вот на случай экзотики какой и для страховки - пригодится.

Answer (score 0):

***NB*** Это была хорошая попытка, но, скорее всего, не заработает как надо. Опора на какие-то интервалы времени, надеясь что всё работает достаточно быстро - это все не надёжно. Я сперва думал что двух миллисекуд хватит. А оказалось что на мощном железе, на пустой странице интервал может быть и больше. Увеличил до десяти миллисекунд. Смотрите сами. Я бы сделал идемпотентный обработчик, хоть это и много работы.

Попробуйте троттлинг в десять миллисекунд:

```
const throttle = (f, delay) => {
    let waitFor = 0;
    return (...args) => {
        const now = new Date().getTime();
        if (now > waitFor) {
            waitFor = now + delay;
            // setTimeout(() => f(...args));
            f(...args);
        }
    };
};

const addEventListeners = (element, types, listener) => {
    const handler = throttle(listener, 10);
    types.forEach(type => element.addEventListener(type, handler));
};

...

    addEventListeners(
        element,
        ['mousedown', 'pointerdown', 'touchstart'],
        event => foo()
    );
```

**P.S.** Интервал выбран в десять миллисекунд потому что:

1. Обработка может производится до 100 раз в секунду, пользователь не заметит пропуска разных событий так как обычный темп обработки не более 60 раз в секунду.
2. Разные логические события произошедшие от одного физического события будут вызываться с малым интервалом по времени.

**P.P.S.** Хочется написать `setTimeout(() => f(...args));`. Но тогда перестанет работать `event.preventDefault();` в теле `f`, а это часто нужно. С другой стороны `f` должен исполняться как можно скорее, иначе троттлинг просто не сработает. Идеально если `f` выполнит `event.preventDefault();` а всю остальную обработку передаст в вызов `setTimeout(...);`.

**P.P.P.S.** С другой стороны, если вам нужен `preventDefault`, то его надо делать без троттлинга во всех обработчиках. Тогда схема другая:

```
const addEventListeners = (element, types, listener, preventDefault = false) => {
    const handler = throttle(listener, 10);
    let h = handler;
    if (preventDefault) {
        h = event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            handler(event);
        };
    }
    types.forEach(type => element.addEventListener(type, h));
};

...

    addEventListeners(
        element,
        ['mousedown', 'pointerdown', 'touchstart'],
        event => foo(),
        preventDefault = true
    );
```

Короче, не было печали, купила баба порося...

Comment: В вашем варианте работают множество обработчиков. К примеру код из первого блока вызывает и `pointerdown` и `mousedown`

Comment: @eccs0103, троттлер допускает только один вызов `foo()` в течении миллисекунды. Обработчиков много, вызов `foo()` один.

Comment: Понимаю. Может клик длится больше миллисекунды. Но происходит двойной вызов. [Сами взгляните](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/jQsq/XVWzkFCYm).

Comment: @eccs0103, вы правы. Я у себя получил разницу в две миллисекунды. Если увеличть задержку до десяти, начнёт фильтровать правильно. Но это игра на грани фола.

Comment: @eccs0103, я поправил ответ, но надежно это работать не будет.

Comment: Увидел, пусть будет. Если не будут решения получше попробую что-то с этим поделать

Comment: разве pointer* не пакрывает все нужды? Pointer Events вроде должны работать на всех устройствах адинаково.

Comment: @Armen посмотрите в нижней части вопроса.